# AngularJs orderBy not working as expected with an int

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am creating an angularJs app that need to be filtered by column post_likes, post_dislikes.

Right now it is not filtering the whole number:
for example:

```
<a id="changeLikes"  href="" ng-click="order('-post_likes')"></a>
<a id="changeDislikes" href="" ng-click="order('-post_dislikes')"></a>
```

When clicking the changeLikes tab above the items sort like so:

```
post_likes => 0
post_likes => 11
post_likes => 2
post_likes => 33
post_likes => 4
```

Dislikes also provides the same result(numbers are sorting by the first integer and not the whole number).

The controller that controls this data is:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
    services.getPosts().then(function(data){
        $scope.posts = data.data;
 $scope.predicate = 'post_id';
      $scope.reverse = false;
      $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
    });
});
```

Data is pulled via PHP with no set restrictions on the SQL statement.

Both columns post_likes and dislikes are int(9) in the MySql DB.

Comment: change `post_likes` to an integer in your model instead of a string.  The sort you are getting is a string sort.  They may be an `int(9)` in your DB, but your PHP that is formatting the JSON is sending them as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Claies was right the Data that was being encoded was all turned to strings, returning my data with the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK fixed the problem.

```
return json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```